# $(2k+1)^{4k+1} = (2k+1) \pmod {4k+2} $ . . . why?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

Well, this must be simple but I seem to be dense at the moment. I checked heuristically for small $k$
$$(2k+1)^{4k+1} = (2k+1) \pmod {4k+2} \tag1 $$ 
but couldn't prove that this is so in general.

For the other quarter of numbers, 
$$(2k)^{4k-1} = 0 \pmod {4k} \tag2 $$
I found at least the (even more simple) solution.

So: is (1) true? and if, what is the proof?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(1)$(2k+1)^{4k+1}-(2k+1)=(2k+1)((2k+1)^{4k}-1)$ which is clearly divisible by $2k+1$

$(2k+1)^{4k}$ is odd, so, $(2k+1)^{4k}-1$  is even.

$\implies gcd(2(2k+1))\mid  ((2k+1)^{4k+1}-(2k+1))$

(2) Let $2^r|| k,$ the highest power of $2$ in $4k$ is $r+2$ and in $(2k)^{4k-1}$ is $(r+1)(4k-1)$ which will be $\ge r+2$  if $k\ge 1$

For other primes $q>2$ , let $q^a||k$ the highest power of $q$ in $4k$ is $a$ and in   $(2k)^{4k-1}$ is $a(4k-1)$  which will be $\ge a$ if $k\ge 1$

Comment: Well, it needed a bit to see this, but I got it now. Thanks!

Comment: @GottfriedHelms, I've added the 2nd answer, could you please check?

Comment: well, that was not needed, because (it is obvious to me that) already with the exponent $2$ we get $(2k)^2 = 4k\cdot k = 0 \pmod{4k} $ and thus for all greater exponents. I'd also simplify your notation for the first proof, but since it is not too complicated we simply might leave it as it is...

Answer (score 1):

For the first one, $(2k+1)^{4k+1} - (2k+1) = (2k+1) \left((2k+1)^{4k} - 1\right)$.

Note that $2 \vert \left((2k+1)^{4k} - 1 \right)$.

Hence, $4k+2 \vert (2k+1)^{4k+1} - (2k+1)$

For the second one. Note that for $k \geq 1$, $(2k)^{4k-1} = 2^3k^3 (2k)^{4k-4}$. Hence, in fact $$(2k)^{4k-1} \equiv 0\pmod{8k^3}$$

Answer (score 1):

The number $(2k+1)^{4k+1}-(2k+1)$ is even so 
$$(2k+1)^{4k+1} \equiv (2k+1) \pmod 2  \ .$$
Since the $$(2k+1)^{4k+1} \equiv (2k+1) \pmod {2k+1}  $$
is obvious and $\gcd{(2,2k+1)}=1$ we conclude that 
$$(2k+1)^{4k+1} \equiv (2k+1) \pmod {4k+2} \ . $$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint** $\rm\,\ a,b\:|\:b^n-b\:\Rightarrow\:lcm(a,b)\:|\:b^n-b.\:$ You have $\rm\:a = 2,\ b\:$ odd, so $\rm\:lcm(a,b) = ab.$

**Remark** $\ $ More generally if $\rm\:a,b\in\Bbb Z,\:$ and $\rm\:f(x)\in \Bbb Z[x]\:$ then

$$\rm a\:|\:f(b),\, b\:|\:f(0)\iff a,b\:|\:f(b)\iff lcm(a,b)\:|\:f(b)$$

Above is the special case $\rm\ f(x) =\, x^n - x.$